# User defined reduction when target cannot be used in intermediate steps of reduction

Tags: c++, openmp

In the following code case, I am trying to add many `std::array` to an `std::span` with OpenMP.

The problem is that `std::span` cannot be used as an intermediate type in a tree reduction of addition operands. So, for that reason, I choose `std::array`.

My problem is in initialization of reduction declaration. Althrough the user-defined reduction is well documented, I did not found many examples of such case of reduction.

Any help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <span>
#include <chrono>


template<int S = 1, typename TT, typename T1>
void muladd(TT &&a, const T1 &b)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i)
        std::forward<TT>(a)[i] += S * b[i];
}

int main()
{
    static constexpr size_t SIZE = 10000;
    static constexpr size_t NUM = 10000;
    std::vector<long long> buffer;
    buffer.resize(SIZE);
    std::fill(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), 0);
    // This is a view
    std::span<long long, SIZE> view(buffer.begin(), SIZE);

    std::vector<std::array<long long, SIZE>> operands;
    operands.resize(NUM);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
        std::fill(operands[i].begin(), operands[i].end(), i + 1);

    #pragma omp declare reduction ( \
        add: \
        std::span<long long, SIZE>,     /* This is the final reduction result type (already defined as 'view') */ \
        std::array<long long, SIZE>:    /* This is the intermediate reductions result type */ \
        muladd(omp_out, omp_in))        /* How the reduction takes place */ \
        initializer( /* How the intermediate reduction type initialized */ \
            std::array<long long, SIZE> omp_priv; \
            std::fill(omp_priv.begin(), omp_priv.end(), 0); \
        )
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(add:view)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
        muladd(view, operands[i]);

    // Print first 10 elements to validate the results (all must be 50005000)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << view[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: C++ can reduce with a `+` reduction on objects for which the `operator+` is defined. I find that easier to write than the `declare reduction`. So you'd need to wrap your `array` in a fairly minimal class. The initialization is then taken care of by the default constructor. FWIW your code looks plausible to me but `std::forward` is not part of my repertoire.